# parsing a date with no time into mysql with python

Tags: python, mysql, date, sqlalchemy

I am loading 3GB data composed of many fields from a csv into SQL using the following loop. I have a date field that is just a date and no time. The problem is I get the output of the dates in the form of 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000000 with the superfluous time. I looked around forums and it is indicated this may be due to a bug connected to a version of software i am using. Is this wrong? Anyone know a solution?

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 

disk_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///df.db') 

for df in pd.read_csv('df.csv', names=my_list, encoding='utf-8'):
     df[["Date"]] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y-%m-%d")
     df.to_sql('data', disk_engine)

df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT Date FROM data LIMIT 10', disk_engine)
df.head()


 Date
 0  2002-11-01 00:00:00.000000
 1  2002-05-30 00:00:00.000000
 2  2002-10-15 00:00:00.000000
 3  2002-05-03 00:00:00.000000
 4  2002-05-24 00:00:00.000000
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless.

Comment: What is the actual issue it presents?

Comment: i dont want the "00:00:00.000000" to be included

Comment: `df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.date`?

Comment: Is the date entry a DateTime entry in the SQL database? Because that will be stored as a full timestamp even if you don't send the clock time together with the date to the db. So it gives you back the full datetime @ 00:00:00

Comment: Please share the CREATE TABLE of table 'data' so can see what is the datatype of the 'Date' column.